# Convertir Query Sql Inner join en Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Como aplicar inner join en linq para la siguiente consulta

```
select * from Familia_Persona
inner join Personas on Personas.IdPersona = Familia_Persona.IdPersona
inner join Parentezco on Parentezco.IdParentezco = 
Familia_Persona.idParentezco
where Familia_Persona.idFamilia = 1
and Parentezco.idParentezco = 1
```

he intentado algo como lo siguiente

```
 var conocerPadre = from fp in db.Familia_Persona
                               join p in db.Personas on fp.IdPersona equals p.IdPersona
                               join pt in db.Parentezco on fp.Parentezco equals pt.IdParentezco
                               where fp.IdFamilia == 1 && pt.IdParentezco == 1
                               select fp;
```

pero me genera error en el segundo join

> El tipo de una de las expresiones de la clausula join es incorrecto. No se pudo realizar inferencia de tipos en la llamada a join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer la condición de tu join es de diferentes tipo,checa si son del mismo tipo fp.Parentezco y pt.IdParentezco

ejemplo:

```
join pt in db.Parentezco on fp.IdParentezco equals pt.IdParentezco
```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo este ejemplo:
// Listado de  estudiantes Matriculado en el curso 1

```
 var reg = from E in estlist
                 join M in mtrlist on E.Id equals M.Idestudiante
                 where M.Idcurso == 1
                 select E;
```

Comment: la he actualizado para que valides lo que he intentado

Comment: @Fernankin podrías mostrar la relación de las tablas?